# Background image badly positioned

Tags: graphics, backgrounds, transparency

This is what I am trying to do: I want to have a document written in Arial 12pt, with a half transparent background image centered in the first page, with customized margins.

This code compiled with XeLaTeX would be alright:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
color=black,
opacity=0.2,
angle=0,
contents={%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{ufpr_marcadagua.jpg}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\BgThispage
\centerline{text}\par
more text
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

But when I reset the margins (code below) as I want the background image gets badly repositioned

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\setlength{\voffset}{-1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{1cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.5cm}

\setlength{\hoffset}{-1in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{2.5cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{2.0cm}

\setlength{\textwidth}{16.5cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{25.2cm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{1cm}

\usepackage[pages=some]{background}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
color=black,
opacity=0.2,
angle=0,
contents={%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{ufpr_marcadagua.jpg}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\BgThispage
\centerline{text}\par
more text
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

How can I position the background image in the center of the page having reset margins?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why don't you use `geometry`? Is there a reason to do it all manually?

Comment: The problem is quite certainly in setting `\voffset` and `\hoffset`

Comment: @TeXnician, it's just that I started doing this without the geometry package, and then I didn't want to use time to learn another way.

Comment: But as @egreg says this will probably change something. Try using it (you'll find easy guides on this site and in the documentation).

Comment: @egreg I get that, but if I change \voffset and \hoffset then I won't get the margins I want. Do you know of a way that I can position the background image at a specific distance from maybe the upper left corner of the textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepared a PDF file which is just an A4 paper sheet with 12pt thick borders. Then I used your code with that picture, getting

[image]

You can see that the amount of shifting is exactly due to `\hoffset` and `\voffset`.

***Never*** change their value in order to ease the setting of the page parameters.

Use `geometry` instead:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\geometry{
  headheight=1cm,
  headsep=0.5cm,
  textwidth=16.5cm,
  textheight=25.2cm,
  heightrounded,
  marginparsep=0.5cm,
  footskip=1cm,
}

\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
color=black,
opacity=0.2,
angle=0,
contents={%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{a4paper.pdf}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\BgThispage
\centerline{text}\par
more text
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So what would you recommend?

Comment: @CRodrigues I added how to set the right dimensions with `geometry`.

Comment: Thanks @egreg. I'll try to shift to `geometry`. Anyway I did as you both said and changed margins using the other parameters and setting the offsets to zero.